# netbeans 8.0.2 doesnt recognize primefaces 5.1 or 5.2 library in jsf framework component

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, web-deployment

I'm work on JSF 2.2 with EJB 3 project on netbeans 8.0.2 and glassfish 4.1 everything work good with primeface 5.0 but I want to use some new component from primefaces 5.1 or 5.2 I try to add primefaces 5.1 library directly to WEB project but always get this error:

> Tag Library supports namespace:
>   http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: inputSwitch

that's mean this component just work on primefaces 5.1 or 5.2

I go to web project properties frameworks components primeface click on more then create new library i add primefaces 5.1 jar file but netbeans doesn't recognize it But it recognize primefaces 5.0.

So any help or explain??

Comment: it's built in with netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: replacing the 5.0 doent work add on top doesnt work

Comment: I am also having the same issue, mine was just working fine until yesterday. I don't really know what went wrong. Please finally get this solved I will appreciate you post your solution, thanks

Comment: Ironically Primeface 5.2 is working well in a newly created project on the same Netbeans. Hence, think this has to do with netbean/maven indexing. Still checking...